# Using System.Net.HttpRequest::EndGetRequestStream

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop 3.1.1 and Mono runtime 3.0.12
I'm trying to work with one of Google.Apis samples ([Tasks.ETagCollision](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg%2FTasks.ETagCollision) for example) on that platform, without any success. 
I fixed all NuGet references so the sample runs, but when I'm trying to create a request to the server using the sample code, I'm getting the following error:

> Missing method
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest::EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult,TransportContext&)
>   in assembly
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.0.12/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll,
>   referenced in assembly
>   /Users/peleyal/code.google.com/google-api-dotnet-client/samples/Tasks.CreateTasks/bin/Debug/System.Net.Http.dll
>
> An error has occured:
>       Method not found: 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream'.
>
> Press any key to display the stacktrace
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream'.   at
>   System.Net.WebAsyncResult.CB (System.Object unused) [0x00000] in
>   :0

I checked and System.dll doesn't contain that overload method (it contains only EndGetRequestStream which gets IAsyncResult, but not an additional TransportContext parameter).
It would be great to be able to run that sample on Mono.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

its clearly missing so i would suggest you to file an issue in mono in [their bugtracker](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi). You can read information about [how to file a good bug report](http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs#How_to_make_a_good_bug_report)

Comment: Thanks! I opened a new issue - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12875 in bugzilla.