# How to use google-api-dotnet-client in mono

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

If I create brand new .NET project (.NET 4.5), then add nuget package **Google.Apis.Discovery.v1**, and paste example code example from
[Google APIs Client Library for .NET - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started). It works.

Then i try to run this program under newest mono(3.4.1 from sources) on ubuntu 14.04. I got nasty

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
'Google.Apis.Discovery.v1.DiscoveryService' from assembly 'Google.Apis.Discovery.v1, 
Version=1.8.1.43, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

In my more complex server application, where i use Analytics API, exception is same.

I really need to access google apis from mono. Also I dont know how to get source for particular generated apis.

Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library doesn't support Mono. Last time I tried to make it work, we had a problem with the System.Net dll. As you can find here: [Using System.Net.HttpRequest::EndGetRequestStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283314/using-system-net-httprequestendgetrequeststream). I'm not sure if this issue was already fixed or not.

Regarding the sources:

1. The core library source is available here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/
2. The generated code (for a specific API) can be download from:
   https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/download/library/calendar/v3/csharp?lv=1.8.1
   You can replace 'calendar' with the specific API, let's say youtube, drive, etc. And you should change v3 to the API version.

Good luck.

Comment: Okey, thank for link to particular API sources, with that, I was able to compile all need sources (GoogleApis,GoogleApis.Core, OAuth, and Google.Apis.Analytics) with normal .NET 4.5.1 (no portable/compatibily hell), no other dependecies only JSON.NET 6.0.3, so it is clean and works nicely, even faster, and under mono with no problems :)
I just hope 1.8.1 is stable enought to stick with it for a while, as updating is not really simple this way :).

Maybe you should look into supporting mono when you have time. Really all you sources are all right!!.

Comment: Maybe just update dependecies.., drop support for some dead platforms (WP7, Silverlight) in never releases. Mono is really making progress lately.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you provide more information about your mono environment. I'll start investigate that soon.

Comment: Yes, if you install very fresh Ubuntu 14.04, then decent version of mono is present in repos (3.2.8, **apt-get install mono-complete**), or you can compile from source, [the best instructions here](http://fsharp.org/use/linux/)